# How do i test django ratings in my application?

Tags: python, django

I have installed [django-ratings](http://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings) application in my django project.

Am wondering how best can i test my app voting functionality because 
django ratings is only allowing me to vote once for the same
user, object and Ip address. 
Is there a way i can disable this checks so that i can just insert 
votes, test my application and when am happy i can enable this checks 
back. 
e.g. you can only run this once in the same machine;

```
myobject.rating.add(score=1, user='user_name', ip_address='127.0.0.1')
```

Again the user need to have been authenticated, unless you use None, 
but again you can only vote once.

Gath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot 'disable' these checks because they're specified in the Vote model:

```
unique_together = (('content_type', 'object_id', 'key', 'user', 'ip_address'))
```

You could edit it but that'd be monkey-patching (and maybe would brake the app).

Consider [writing tests](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/), or if you just want to have some votes filled just for the purpose of development, use fixtures (which are also useful in tests).

Comment: Hmmm, thought so, started writing external testing app, that populates the necessary tables and fields. I wish Crammer would add some flag like "Development mode" and "production mode" would be nice.  Thanks a lot.